# How to rosmake pcl_ros in Mac OS X?

Tags: pcl, macos, macos-lion, osx, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I'm trying to rosmake pcl_ros but I'm bumping into this error:

```
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package pcl_ros
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  Failed to invoke /Users/cabrita/ros/ros/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only pcl_ros
  CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKTargets.cmake:16 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
    Command add_executable() is not scriptable
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/local/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKConfig.cmake:231 (INCLUDE)
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.7/share/cmake/Modules/FindVTK.cmake:73 (FIND_PACKAGE)
    /Users/cabrita/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/vtk_include.cmake:1 (find_package)
  
  
  [rospack] warning: got non-zero exit status from executing backquote expression "ret="-I/Users/cabrita/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/include/pcl-1.1/ -I`cmake -P /Users/cabrita/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/vtk_include.cmake`" && echo $ret" in [/Users/cabrita/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/manifest.xml]
  [rospack] error in backquote expansion for pcl_ros
  
  
  CMake Error at /Users/cabrita/ros/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'pcl_ros'.  Look
    above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken
    dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /Users/cabrita/ros/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:230 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:4 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

I have vtk installed:

```
$ brew install vtk
Warning: vtk already installed
```

I am running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 and ROS electric, I followed the tutorial on how to install ROS using Homebrew.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30760/how-to-rosmake-pcl_ros-in-mac-os-x?/) by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 591 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't, but it is possible in fuerte.

**UPDATE:**

Look at this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/32706/failed-depth_image_proc-build-on-osx) to see what you have to do for getting rosdep to find pcl.

Also, I got ros_pcl to compile but in my efforts to get OpenNI working with ROS I messed something up and now ros_pcl won't compile again and I can't seem to fix it. :(

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2012-04-27**:
Thanks Kevin, time to update to Fuerte!!! It's just that it is so hard to get things working on OS X I'm always a bit lazy on updating!

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-04-27**:
There are still a lot of issues for OSX in fuerte, but I got pcl_ros to compile, but I can't get openni_camera to work ... so good luck!

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-04-29**:
Hi Kevin, did you follow the homebrew instructions?  I get an error about "no definition of [pcl] on [osx]" during the rosdep install phase when attempting to build pcl_ros fuerte on osx.

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-04-29**:
Hi Kevin, did you follow the homebrew instructions?  I get an error about "no definition of [pcl] on [osx]" during the rosdep install phase when attempting to build pcl_ros fuerte on osx.

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-04-29**:
Hi Kevin, did you follow the homebrew instructions?  I get an error about "no definition of [pcl] on [osx]" during the rosdep install phase when attempting to build pcl_ros fuerte on osx.